# C# file access error

Tags: c#, ftp, file-access

I have the following C# code :

```
string selectedFile = "D:\..\IMGP2695.JPG";
MyImage myImage = new MyImage();
Image image = Image.FromFile(selectedFile);
string thumbnail_name = CreateThumbnail(image);
myImage.height = image.Height + "px";
myImage.width = image.Width + "px";
ftp.upload(myImage.internalName, selectedFile, directory);


 The process cannot access the file `'D:\..\IMGP2695.JPG'` because it is being used by another process.
```

I get this error when the code try to run `ftp.upload`. I know what the error means but i don't know what to do to close the handle to the opened file.

Comment: Why are you opening it in the first place?

Comment: The file is the result of an OpenFileDialog. I don't open it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `dispose` image object by wrapping  `Image.FromFile` with `using`:

```
string selectedFile = "D:\..\IMGP2695.JPG";
MyImage myImage = new MyImage();
string thumbnail_name = string.empty;
using(Image image = Image.FromFile(selectedFile)){
   thumbnail_name = CreateThumbnail(image);
   myImage.height = image.Height + "px";
   myImage.width = image.Width + "px";
}
ftp.upload(myImage.internalName, selectedFile, directory);
```

Comment: i should use "using". thanks for your example. i will change my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you calling `Image image = Image.FromFile(selectedFile);` *before* uploading , for some reason.

If you look on  [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/4sahykhd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation you will see the following string:

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

That means, that according to the code provided, you can init Image even *after* the upload finished.

```
ftp.upload("NAME_OF_THE_FILE_RECOVERED_FROM_FILE_ITSELF", selectedFile, directory);

Image image = Image.FromFile(selectedFile);
```

Comment: Perfect. Now is working. Thanks a lot. I did not think of that line. Sorry. Can you give me an idea on how to upload the image with another thread ? The form remains freeze until the upload is done and it's not nice.